# Bitbucket pipeline not able to propagate some commands installed on default

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bitbucket-pipelines

```
image: python:3.7

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Install and Configure Google Cloud SDK
        script:
          - export BUILD_TAG=stage-xxx:$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER
          - echo $GCLOUD_API_KEYFILE | base64 -d > ${HOME}/gcloud-service-key.json
          - apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
          - curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash -s -- --disable-prompts --install-dir=/usr/local/gcloud
          - export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/bin
          - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=${HOME}/gcloud-service-key.json
          - gcloud config set project $PROJECT_ID
          - gcloud config list
          - gcloud components install kubectl
          - gcloud components install gsutil

    - step:
        name: Build Docker image and push to GCR
        services:
          - docker
        script:
          - export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/bin
          - export BUILD_TAG=stage-kredily:$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER
          - gcloud container clusters get-credentials gke-xxx-xxx-as1-service-01 --zone asia-south1-a --project prj-srv-xxx-xxx-01
          - gsutil -m rm -r gs://bkt-xxx-static-files-01/static/*
          - gsutil -m rsync -r static/ gs://bkt-xxxx-static-files-01/static/
          - docker build -t asia-south1-docker.pkg.dev/prj-srv-xxxx-beta-01/repo-xxxx-stage-as1-01/$BUILD_TAG .
          - gcloud auth configure-docker asia-south1-docker.pkg.dev
          - docker push asia-south1-docker.pkg.dev/prj-srv-xxxx-beta-01/repo-xxxx-stage-as1-01/$BUILD_TAG

    - step:
        name: Deploy to QA App Server
        image: gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/google-cloud-cli:alpine
        script:
          - export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/bin
          - kubectl set image deployment/xx-app xx-app=asia-south1-docker.pkg.dev/prj-srv-xx-beta-01/repo-xx-stage-as1-01/stage-xx:latest--record --namespace=xx-beta
```

`

Here you can see that I have installed google cloud components at the default stage mainly gsutil and kubectl, which needs to be used in the subsequent steps, however I am always getting below error:

```
bash: gcloud: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/step-options/#The-Step-property

> *Each step in your pipeline will start a separate Docker container to run the commands configured in the script option.*

So, it's not that pipelines are "unable to propagate commands installed on default", it's that they won't BY DESIGN.

You should never split the setup of a step elsewhere. Just cache whatever makes sense to cache so that subsequent executions are faster https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/cache-dependencies/

Also, it makes much more sense to simply use a docker image specific for the main tooling you are using. E.g. using `gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/google-cloud-cli` instead of installing gcloud in a python image!